# array muestra información errónea javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un array que al hacerle `console.log(array[variable].lastStep)` me muestra el valor correcto, sin embargo, si hago `console.log(array[variable])` también muestra información correcta, pero al expandirlo, muestra el lastStep mal, dejo imagen

[image: resultado]

dejo también fragmento de código donde realizo la asignación

```
if(copiaDatosP[copiaCount].step[j] == lastStep){
                        console.log('entra '+cantidad);
                        copiaDatosP[copiaCount].lastStep = 3;
                        console.log(copiaDatosP[copiaCount].lastStep);
                        console.log(copiaDatosP[copiaCount]);
                    } else {
                        copiaDatosP[copiaCount].lastStep = 0;
                    }
                    steps[cantidad] = (4-(primerTrim/13))*13+copiaDatosP[copiaCount].step[j];
                    cantidad++;
```

Comment: Porque escribes `lastStep = 0` en tu codigó, el objecto va a actualizar antes de que puedes inspeccionarlo en la terminal. Primero lastStep es 3 y despues 0.  Cuando escribes `copiaDatosP[copiaCount].lastStep`  se mostrará el valor exacto que tenía en ese momento.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias, ya lo resolví